# why dbcontext.savechanges() donot clear tracked entites of this dbcontext in efcore

Tags: entity-framework-core, automapper, savechanges

I have an error on update entities use efcore and automapper:

`Entity cannot be tracked because another instance is with the same key value`

I saw some answers and solved the problem，but I confused why this error occured when I update entities after savechanges.

#### my code

```
            var addEntityList = _wcsDbContext.ConveyorAddrInfos.Where(x => x.ConveyorAddr == "1007").AsNoTracking().ToList();
            var addrInfos = _mapper.Map<List<ConveyorAddrInfoDto>>(addEntityList);
            if (!addrInfos.Any())
            {
                _logger.LogError("error");
                return;
            }
            // do something like this ...
            foreach (var info in addrInfos)
            {
                info.UnitId = "Test";

            }

            var dest = _mapper.Map(addrInfos, addEntityList);
            _wcsDbContext.ConveyorAddrInfos.UpdateRange(dest);
            _wcsDbContext.SaveChanges();

            //=====================update 2 times=======================

            var addEntityList2 = _wcsDbContext.ConveyorAddrInfos.Where(x => x.ConveyorAddr == "1007").AsNoTracking().ToList();
            var addrInfos2 = _mapper.Map<List<ConveyorAddrInfoDto>>(addEntityList2);

            // do something...
            foreach (var conveyorAddInfoDto in addrInfos2)
            {
                conveyorAddInfoDto.UnitId = string.Empty;

            }

            var dest2 = _mapper.Map<List<ConveyorAddrInfo>>(addrInfos2);
            _wcsDbContext.ConveyorAddrInfos.UpdateRange(dest2);
            _wcsDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I solved by the code following

```
  // add this after first savechanges
  foreach (var entityEntry in _wcsDbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries())
  {
     entityEntry.State = EntityState.Detached;
  }
```

or change the map method

```
var dest = _mapper.Map(addrInfos, addEntityList);
```

But I m confused why savechanges() donot clear tracked entites of this dbcontext in efcore

Answer (score 0):

I think this GitHub issue sheds some light on your question:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9118

From what I understood, the `ChangeTracker` is primarily not cleared after a call to `SaveChanges(Async)` because the caller might be interested in generated values from the DB (like e.g. the primary key). These properties are populated back into memory for the entities (for subsequent use).